# ContikiOS restarting z1 nodes from within the code

Tags: contiki

Is there a way to restart nodes (for example Zolertia Z1) from within the code? I know there is a command which allows restarting through serial make z1-reset but is there any way to restart it from within the code ?

Comment: Asking this question on SuperUser might get better results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use watchdog for this purpose:

```
#include "dev/watchdog.h"

void do_reboot(void)
{
   watchdog_reboot();
}
```